# How do i make a custom button in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

i need help with my app. iam new to flutter and wanted to try to make a homepage with an intresting button. i have design my homepage in figma but i dont really know how to make the button to be the same, so here's my figma UI design that i want to implement

[image]

i use an SVG icon for the button.

and so far in my code, my HomePage only looks like this

[image]

and btw this is my HomePage code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get_navigation/get_navigation.dart';
import 'package:medreminder/NewsArticle/news_home.dart';
import 'Reminder/ui/home_reminder.dart';
import 'Reminder/ui/widgets/button.dart';
import 'package:medreminder/main_reminder.dart';
import 'package:medreminder/home_page.dart';

void main() {
  // debugPaintSizeEnabled = true;
  runApp(const HomePage());
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Medicine Reminder App'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Stack(
              children: [
                Image.asset(
                  'images/MenuImg.jpg',
                  width: 600,
                  height: 200,
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ],
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 10.0),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              children: [
                ElevatedButton(
                  child: const Text('Reminder'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).push(
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const ReminderHomePage()),
                    );
                  },
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  child: const Text('News & Article'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).push(
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const NewsHomePage()),
                    );
                  },
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  child: const Text('Healty Food Recipe'),
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

thankyou guys for the attention, any help would mean so much to me. thankyou

Comment: are those image in your assets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you have those images in your `asset` folder, so you can use this widget to build your custom button:

```
Widget buildCustomButton(String imagePath, String title, Function()? onTap) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: onTap,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Container(
            clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
            height: 50,
            width: 50,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
            ),
            child: Image.asset(imagePath, fit: BoxFit.none),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 8,
          ),
          Text(
            title,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

and use it like this:

```
buildCustomButton('assets/images/reminder.png', 'Reminder', () {
        print("Reminder click");
      }),
```

[image]

Comment: its not an image, but an SVG icon. will it still work?

Comment: you need change Image.asset to svgplayer, what do you use for show svg?

Comment: i use microsoft edge to open my svg

Comment: no I mean what package do you use to show svg in flutter?

Comment: i haven't use any svg's in my flutter

Answer (score 1):

wrap the widget you want to be a button with inkwell, you can make buttons as you want.

[image]

```
InkWell(
              onTap: () {},
              child: Container(
                child: FlutterLogo(
                  size: 80,
                ),
              ))
```

Comment: what if i want an image as the button sir?

Comment: You can add an image with png or jpg extension from the asset. Image.asset('images/cat.png')

Answer (score 1):

Make design as you want then wrap that image with GestureDetector like this.

```
     GestureDetector (onTap:()
                     {Your Method('Where you want to naviagate')},
                     child:Your Design})
```

Comment: will there be any errors if i change my ElevatedButton to GestureDetector?

Answer (score 0):

I created a custom button in Flutter using various methods.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sbbwu_navigator/utils/app_color.dart';

class CustomButton extends StatelessWidget {
  CustomButton({Key? key,this.height,this.width,required this.title,this.onTap,this.loading=false}) : super(key: key);
  double? height;
  double? width;
  String title;
  VoidCallback? onTap;
  bool loading;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: onTap,
        child: Container(
          height: height,
          width: double.infinity,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: AppColor.primaryColor,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
          ),
          child: loading ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(color: Colors.white,)) :Center(
              child: Text(
                title,
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```